# VSC and C++ returning an error, using gcc installed via mingw

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When ever I try to run a build task from any program, it gives me an error stating that there is an undefined reference to `std::cout`, `std::cin`, and stuff like `std:basic_istearm<char>`. I've tried changing terminal `integrated.defaultProfile` but that doesn't work. My gcc, gdb and g++ installation are all there as well

I've tried running all sorts of programs, none of them work. It fails with exit code -1 and the exit statement:

```
The terminal process failed to launch
```

Comment: can you show some code ? it looks like you forgot #include <stdio>

Comment: Please show both your code and the full error message (add it to your question).  It actually sounds like a linker error.

Comment: @141592653 That would be `<iostream>`.

Comment: I'm guessing you're compiling with gcc instead of g++